# Display the validation popup after select all the compulsary fields

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have an issue with a filterbutton : when some client selects all the compulsary field then the grid have to be filtered otherwise it must to display a popup message : "select all compulsary field".

Here in my fiddle, I have 3 dropdowns and 2 datepicker. When we select all than filterbutton filters the data, otherwise it must show the message.In this fiddle dropdowns is not working with grid because i didn't placed any code between dropdown and grid but datetimpicker is working.

In [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/exakic/61/edit) I need to display the popup validation.
Here all are compulsary field which is in fiddle

code:

```
if(datetimepicker1 ===""&&datetimepicker2 ==="") {
    $("#filter-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
}
```

This way i am tring but i want to validate all the 5 controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to add the test in the `click` event of the `filter` button :

```
$("#filter").on("click", function () {
    var mindate = $('#datetimepicker1').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var maxdate = $('#datetimepicker2').data("kendoDatePicker").value();

    // Check if min date has been filled
    if(!mindate) {
        alert("You have not filled the min date...");
        return false;
    }

    // Check if max date has been filled
    if(!maxdate) {
        alert("You have not filled the max date...");
       return false;
    }

    // the rest of your logic...
}
```

Instead of an `alert`, you can put your window (`$("#filter-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().open();`), but you should keep the `return false` after in order to not filter the results...

Comment: ya thank you for answer but i want to display validation as summary in popup

Comment: ya your right but it will display separately for each any every control right?

Comment: You can have for both, by writing : `if(!mindate || !maxdate) { $("#filter-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().open(); return false;}`...

Comment: You have put your test after the `grid.dataSource.filter(condition);` so that it shows the updated table before raising the popup. And I don't see the `filter-msg` popup defined in your code!

Comment: ya i got it i got the solution for datepicker but dropdownlist is not working and one more is here it is showing only one message can we show different messages for different controls based on those names?

Comment: Yes you can set the property `content` of your window : `var content = ""; if(!mindate) content += "<div class=\"k-error-colored\">mindate is not defined!</div>"; if(!maxdate) content += "<div class=\"k-error-colored\">maxdate is not defined!</div>";  $("#filter-msg").data("kendoWindow").content(content).center().open();`

Comment: actually this is my application code can you modify here please http://jsbin.com/exakic/63/edit  and ddl controls not binding why i dont know but in apllication it's ddl is binded

Comment: by using "id " can we write condtion?

Comment: I am more familiar with Jsfiddle, so I have switched your code to this site : http://jsfiddle.net/XHW3w/1/ . Try it and let me know if there is again any issue...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27855/discussion-between-samuel-caillerie-and-sandeep)

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time

Comment: hi samuel i have a small problem in this functionality can you please help me?

Comment: hi samuel issue is in this functionality is fiter is not applying to mozilla and IE.can u help me please?